# React Redux Test failed because it can't fetch data throught action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test my smart component using Jest and Enzyme but it has no data to render because it supposed to be fetched trought actions. Error is: `getTasks is not a function`

```
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Main', () => {
  describe('when loading is true', () => {
    it('should render loading div', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(<Main.WrappedComponent loading={true} />);
      expect(wrapper.html()).toEqual('<div>Loading</div>');
      wrapper.unmount();
    });
  });
});
```

And this is component I'm trying to test, it fetching data trought actions and then doing some stuff with them, but if there is no data(`loading === true`) it just renders the `<div>` with "Loading" text. `getTasks()` just `import` the data:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.handleData = this.handleData.bind(this);
    this.handleHigh = this.handleHigh.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { getTasks } = this.props;
    getTasks();
  }

  render() {
    const { data, loading } = this.props;
    if (!loading) {
      this.handleData(data);
      return (
          {data.map(task => {
            if (task.obj_status === 'active') 
              return (
               // Doing some stuff with data here
              );
    } else {
      return <div>Loading</div>;
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.main.data,
  loading: state.main.loading
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  ...bindActionCreators(
    {
      getTasks: loadTasks,
      dispatch
    },
    dispatch
  )
});

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Main)
);
```

Comment: Could you show WrappedComponent ?

Comment: You need to mock a response from server. You can use a nock module

Comment: @AdrianPażucha done

Comment: @IuriiBudnikov it's just import from local storage, no server or even `fetch` func, but I got what you mean. Can u send me a link on example?

Comment: @IuriiBudnikov I checked `nock` but it's only for HTTP requests, I have no HTTP there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in getTasks as a function into your props:

```
const wrapper = mount(<Main.WrappedComponent loading={true} getTasks={() => {}} />);
```

As when Enzyme mounts it will invoke componentDidMount and will call the undefined prop and blow up

Comment: Thank you a lot! This worked for me. But if I want to test correct render of this component, what I suppose to do with `getTasks()`?

Comment: I'd suggest you stub this function using Sinon and you can ensure that it gets called when you expect it to. I would have another test that provides `data` into your component and then you can assert that `map` function is correctly outputting elements

Comment: So just describe dummy `data` in my test?

Comment: Yup, with the correct format that you are expecting. You can provide some with `obj_status` of 'active', to test that if statement in there too, as well as one with a different `obj_status` and ensure that that element doesn't get rendered

Comment: Ok, got it! Thank you a lot again!

Comment: No problem! A few small things, I'd suggest applying a filter before your map, and remove the items that have the incorrect obj_status, its a lot cleaner than conditionally returning inside a map function. 

If you look into arrow functions you can also remove the .bind(this) in the constructor too

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is mock function:

```
const getTasksMock = jest.fn();
const wrapper = mount(<Main.WrappedComponent loading={true} getTasks={getTasksMock}/>);
```

Then you are able check invoking function by for example: `toHaveBeenCalled()`
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tohavebeencalled